# Pagespeed insights for country specific domain

Tags: pagespeed-insights

My website is hosted on a server in Australia (com.au).  I do not use a CDN

I only target an Australian audience

Does pagespeed use an Australian server? It seems to me,  if pagespeed servers are not in Australia then it will result in a poor score?

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: use lighthouse tests available in chrome dev tools to measure your website. for region specific sites, this provides better visibility comppared to pagespeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based on this answer Pagespeed might report different results depending on your location.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110397/do-pagespeed-insights-vary-by-location